# AngularJs and Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I wanted to try to build something with AngularJs and Parse as the back end. 
I found some tutorials now I have this in one of my controllers:

```
 var Game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
 var query = new Parse.Query(Game);     

 query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.games = results.map(function(obj) {
        return {points: obj.get("points"), gameDate: obj.get("gameDate"),  parseObject: obj};
      });
    });
  },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

in my view I have a ng-repeat and everything works fine, but when I try to get the objectId or the ceatedAt I can't.

I add:

```
      $scope.sessions = results.map(function(obj) {
        return {points: obj.get("points"), gameDate: obj.get("gameDate"),  gameId: obj.get("objectId"), createdAt: obj.get("createAt"), parseObject: obj};
```

But in my view they are not displayed, although when I check the XHR responses this fields are present.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the objectId and createdAt as properties of obj, as follows:

```
var objectId = obj.id;
var updatedAt = obj.updatedAt;
var createdAt = obj.createdAt;
```

See the [Retrieving Objects section of the Parse JavaScript Guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving).

Comment: Yes I looked around and found this. Thank you!