# retrieve data with angularJS and parse

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an app using ionic framework which is angularJS and parse.com. And I would like to get data from parse.com into my app so I use the code.

```
var Category = Parse.Object.extend("category");
var query = new Parse.Query(Category);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    $scope.category = results;
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

and in HTML page I put

```
<a ng-repeat="cat in category" nav-clear menu-close class="item" href="#/app/board/{{cat.id}}">
                {{cat.name_en}}
            </a>
```

to repeat my data.

the *results* data is

```
        [{"name_en":"property","name_th":"บ้าน/อพาร์ทเม้นท์","objectId":"tomiG6VzCd","createdAt":"2014-08-18T08:32:13.956Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-18T08:32:19.617Z"},{"name_en":"jobs","name_th":"หางาน/จ้างงาน","objectId":"9Aop8vzn6l","createdAt":"2014-08-18T08:32:32.792Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-18T08:32:36.485Z"},{"name_en":"motors","name_th":"ซื้อ/ขายรถยนต์","objectId":"vLwjhWVJOm","createdAt":"2014-08-18T08:32:55.475Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-18T08:32:58.610Z"},{"name_en":"other","name_th":"อื่นๆ","objectId":"6xVpnrSMrW","createdAt":"2014-08-18T08:33:08.178Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-18T08:33:13.453Z"}]
```

but when I ten the app, it seem like information doesn't show on the list, so my app displayed like this picture.

[image]

like they and see how many rows from parse.com but they can't get `name_en` to show on the list.

any suggestion to fix this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: ahh I just found the answer.

see this topic [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653066/angularjs-and-parse?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653066/angularjs-and-parse?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The success and error callbacks are executed in the context of the Parse library, so Angular is not made aware of the changes on `$scope.category`. Try to use `$scope.$apply` to make Angular aware of the change:

```
success: function(results) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.category = results;
    });
},
```

Comment: still doesn't work. when I change from {{cat.name_en}} to {{cat.id}} they shows the id of each list but just doesn't work for other attribute.

Answer (score -1):

In your Html, instead of

```
{{cat.name_en}}
```

put

```
{{cat.get('name_en')}}
```